# What is the Burke Potential?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, potential, definition

I have very much enjoyed William L. Burke's *Applied Differential Geometry*. Reading around on the [web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_L._Burke) it seems that he discovered something which is called the (retarded) Burke Potential. Can anyone explain succinctly what it is?

Comment: One can find an exercise discussing the significance of Burke potential [here](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/AndreiStarinets/TUTORIALS/GR-HT-2021/gr-problem-set-4-2021.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, the Wikipedia page sadly does not provide a source. Searching Google scholar for the term "Burke potential", the term only appears to be used on the back of the 2020 reprint of the publication *Spacetime, geometry, cosmology* by Burke, which might be a good source to look for its description.

The potential is mentioned in the [memorial speech by Johan Faulkner](http://texts.cdlib.org/view?docId=hb0z09n6nn;NAAN=13030&doc.view=content&chunk.id=div00012&toc.depth=1&brand=oac4&anchor.id=0) as published by the The Online Archive of California. Here it is stated that

> Bill himself would mainly emphasize these aspects of his **graduate work**. [...] Almost by intuition he discovered an extremely small time-varying part of the local gravitational potential (and thus force-field), with a spatial form normally thrown away in the static case, and effectively missed by both Newton and Einstein. This reactive **Burke Potential**, its consequences traced through its linkage to the distant waves, slowly drains energy and angular momentum from orbiting systems that Newton would have thought eternal.

(Emphasis mine.)

This points us towards Burke's thesis [The coupling of gravitational radiation to nonrelativistic sources](https://thesis.library.caltech.edu/4091/), where indeed such a term is discussed in section IV, with an explicit form presented in section E as far as I can understand.

Note that the statement that it was dubbed the Burke potential appears to be contradicted by the fact that "Burke potential" does not seem to appear in any publications indexed by Google Scholar.

Comment: This must be the oldest question I have ever answered.